# What is the difference between the operating system and the kernel?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I do not understand the difference between operating system and kernel. Can someone please explain it?

Comment: Why isn't Windows 7 called a kernel?

Comment: think car/engine

Comment: @Roque Santa Cruz: for the same reason computers are not called screens.

Comment: Because it's an operating system. :)
But seriously, a kernel is just a core process that owns everything handles the fundamentals. The win7 kernel is the thing that splits the processor time between all of your applications, manages the CPU and the memory, etc.

Comment: This is definitely an off-topic question. Not directly related to StackExchange. Incase you're still looking for the answer, see this thread (duplicate) here…. it has every possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013937/what-is-an-os-kernel-how-does-it-differ-from-an-operating-system
@Moderators : Please close this !!

Comment: @Anycorn more like Engine/ECU

Answer (score 101):

The [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel) is part of the [operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and closer to the hardware it provides
low level services like:

- device driver
- process management
- memory management
- system calls

An operating system also includes applications like the user interface (shell, gui, tools, and services).

Comment: Exactly. This is why calling Linux an Operating System is a misnomer :)

Answer (score 51):

The difference between an operating system and a kernel:

The kernel is a part of an operating system. The operating system is the software package that communicates directly to the hardware and our application.  The kernel is the lowest level of the operating system. The kernel is the main part of the operating system and is responsible for translating the command into something that can be understood by the computer.
The main functions of the kernel are:

1. memory management
2. network management
3. device driver
4. file management
5. process management

Answer (score 16):

Basically the Kernel is the interface between hardware (devices which are available in Computer) and Application software is like MS Office, Visual Studio, etc.

If I answer "what is an OS?" then the answer could be the same. Hence the kernel is the part & core of the OS.

The very sensitive tasks of an OS like memory management, I/O management, process management are taken care of by the kernel only.

So the ultimate difference is:

1. Kernel is responsible for Hardware level interactions at some specific range. But the OS is like hardware level interaction with full scope of computer.
2. Kernel triggers SystemCalls to tell the OS that this resource is available at this point of time. The OS is responsible to handle those system calls in order to utilize the resource.